# Git command to know the Files changed of a Pull Request (PR) of a forked repository

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I have a GitHub repository which is forked by many other repository. One of such repository has made a pull request and wants to merge it with my repository(master) which i can clearly see in GitHub.

I have a shell script which needs to make a CURL (Https POST) call against each files changed of the PR (the files changed will always have a Json content).The content of the files changed will act as a payload of the Curl call.

Is there any git command to know the files changed and its content of the PR ?[image: As shown in the screenshot. Is there a git command to know the Files changed from my repository GameServices:master of the pull request made]